# Spreading flyway profiles over phases

Tags: maven, flyway

I'm trying to create separate profiles which using flyway-maven-plugin, but phase definition doesn't work properly. Which mean that when i use both profiles i have an error on execution because i guess "drop-create-database" using configuration from "migrate-database" thus it`s failed. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>drop-create</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <table>MIGRATION_LOG</table>
                        <sqlMigrationPrefix>EMP_</sqlMigrationPrefix>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>drop-create-database</id>
                            <!-- Need to garantee order of execution -->
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                                <goal>migrate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>migrate</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <table>MIGRATION_LOG</table>
                        <sqlMigrationPrefix>ALL_</sqlMigrationPrefix>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>migrate-database</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>migrate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: In which order are both executions actually executed?

Comment: Sorry i've fixed description. Not order guess when i run "clean package -Pdrop-create, migrate" it uses for "drop-create" configuration from "migrate" instead of it's own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the configuration per execution instead of per plugin. Otherwise a later configuration for the same plugin will overwrite previous ones.

This means your pom.xml should look something like this:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>drop-create</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-create-database</id>
                        <!-- Need to garantee order of execution -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                            <table>MIGRATION_LOG</table>
                            <sqlMigrationPrefix>EMP_</sqlMigrationPrefix>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>migrate</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>migrate-database</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                            <table>MIGRATION_LOG</table>
                            <sqlMigrationPrefix>ALL_</sqlMigrationPrefix>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Dammit, i thought i tried this ... apparently i had a mistake! Thanks a lot, works fine.